# Generic Database Method

Tags: java, generics

I have a Java class that retrieves data from a Drupal CMS.  There will eventually be quite a number of content types in Drupal that I need to pull into Java and cache.  Because of the way Drupal works, each content type is a separate database view.

I have the following method which is called by the service layer, and it returns a particular object type.  However, my fear is the proliferation of these methods for each content type.

Can someone suggest a way to make it more generic?  The database method is shown in the 2nd code sample.  I don't know if I can make it generic, too, and if it is worth it.  Maybe I can call one method in the first method, and have the 2nd method use a case statement.

```
public DeliverySchedule getDeliverySchedule(final String cmsKey) { //     <---- make return type (Del Schedule) generic

    String cacheKey = TYPEDS + cmsKey;
    DeliverySchedule cmsInstance = CMSObjectCache.getCachedCMSObject(cacheKey, DeliverySchedule.class);   // Make generic

    // Object not found in cache, go to database.
    if (cmsInstance == null) {
        try {
            cmsInstance = getDeliveryScheduleFromDB(cmsKey);   //  <---- How can I make this generic so I can avoid DRY?
            CMSObjectCache.putCachedCMSObject(cacheKey, new CMSObject(DeliverySchedule.class, cmsInstance));
            return cmsInstance;
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return cmsInstance;
    }
}
```

The database access method, specific to the content type above:

```
    // Called from above
private List<DeliverySchedule> getDeliverySchedulesFromDB() {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    final String sql = "select * "
            + "         from cmsutil.delivery_schedules as m "
            + "         where m.effdate = (select max(mm.effdate) "
            + "                            from cmsutil.delivery_schedules as mm "
            + "                            where mm.cms_key = m.cms_key "
            + "                            and mm.effdate <= current_date)";


    List<DeliverySchedule> listcmsObject = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new DeliveryScheduleMapper());
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new DeliveryScheduleMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd have a DAO for each table or view (an interface for the DAO and a class that implements it). That way if a specific table schema changes, your changes are isolated to one DAO class.

You could generalize the content type to have a single interface and a class that implements the interface for each content type. This should allow you to adapt to changes with the generic content type layer, the specific content type, and at the data access layer.

I agree it can potentially turn into a lot of code, but if each component is decoupled from the others it gives you flexibility when changing/adding components or dealing with schema changes. Decoupling and abstraction can be painful in the short term but in the long run tends to pay off across an engineering team.

I enjoy questions/discussions such as these and am always open to suggestions or other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

To create new instances of your class, you need to use the reflection gear on the class object. So what you do is you use a generic class whose instances have a record of that class. Let's say a lll your beans extend mybean;

```
abstract class<T extends MyBean> Mapper implements T {
    abstract void map(ResultSet rs);
}

class DAO<T extends MyBean> {
    Class<Mapper<T>> theMapperClass;
    DAO(Class<T> clazz) { 
        this.theMapperClass = getMapperClassFor(clazz); 
    }

    List<T> getAList() {
        List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
        ResultSet rs = runTheQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            l.add(theMapperClaxx.newInstance().map(rs));
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

That kind of thing.

```
   DAO<Foo> fooDao = new Dao<Foo>(Foo.class);
   List<Foo> l = fooDao.getAList();

   List<? extends MyBean> l = someDao.getAList();

   static <T extends Mybean> List<T> boink(Class<T> clazz) {
       DAO<T> tDao = (DAO<T>) daoMap.get(clazz);
       return tDao.getAList();
   }

   List<Foo> l = boink(Foo.class);
```